# Flat price for each currency in Virtuemart

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

Currently Virtuemart uses a converter module: **convertECB.php**.
Such module fetches exchange rates from a server and convert one currency into another.

Is it possible to set a fixed prices for each product and currency?

ie we have USD, EUR and GBP and we'd like prices as follows:

- Product 1: 15 USD
- Product 1: 10 GBP
- Product 1: 12 EUR
- Product 2: 29 USD
- Product 2: 20 GBP
- Product 2: 23 EUR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to hack the VM core to achieve what you want to do. The converter is used so that the price can be calculated from a single price field in the VM product info database table. If you are not going to calculate the price based on exchange rates, then you have to have additional price fields where you can enter the price of each currency you want to accept.

If you just want to have even number prices, then you can hack convertECB.php to round the price before dispalying it.